# Yii:Why images are not resized correctly ?

Tags: image, yii, upload, resize, yii-extensions

I am using image extension for image re sizing but they are not resized according to the parameters which i gave. Here is my code.Is there any mistake in my code or what. Images which are resized have dimension equal to "800*533"
 but not exactly equals to 800*600.

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Business;

            // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
            // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

            if(isset($_POST['Business']))
            {
                         $rnd = rand(0, 9999);  // generate random number between 0-9999

                $model->attributes = $_POST['Business'];

                $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
                $fileName = "{$rnd}-{$uploadedFile}";  // random number + file name
                $model->image = $fileName;


                if ($model->save()) {
                     if(!empty($uploadedFile))  // check if uploaded file is set or not
                {
                    //$uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot')."/img".$filename);
                    $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath . '/../img/' . $fileName);
                    $image = Yii::app()->image->load(Yii::app()->basePath . '/../img/' . $fileName);
                   $image->resize(800, 600);
                    $image->save(Yii::app()->basePath . '/../img/' . $fileName);
                    }

                    $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
                }
            }

            $this->render('create', array(
                'model' => $model,
            ));
        }
```

Comment: change 

$image->resize(800, 600);  to
$image->resize(800, 600, Image::NONE);

Answer (score 0):

First advise. Don't store not resized image you can use 
tempName property of CUploadedFile

```
 $image = Yii::app()->image->load($uploadedFile->tempName );
                   $image->resize(800, 600);
                    $image->save(Yii::app()->basePath . '/../img/' . $fileName);
```

About resize i think you have to calculate size of resized picture.
Here is my code

```
 protected static function  getImgBox($img,$width,$height,$bySide,$boxType){
        $img_width=$img->getSize()->getWidth();
        $img_height=$img->getSize()->getHeight();
        $newWidth =0;
        $newHeight=0;

        switch($boxType){
            case self::BOX_TYPE_FILL:
            {
                $newWidth=$width;
                $newHeight=$height;
            }
                break;
            case self::BOX_TYPE_WO:{

                if($bySide==self::BY_SIDE_WIDTH) {

                    $newWidth = $width;
                    $newHeight = $img_height * $newWidth / $img_width;
                }

                if($bySide==self::BY_SIDE_HEIGHT){
                    $newHeight=$height;
                    $newWidth = $img_width*$newHeight/$img_height;
                }


            }
                break;

            case self::BOX_TYPE_INSIDE:{

                $newWidth = $width;
                $newHeight = $img_height * $newWidth / $img_width;

                if($newHeight>=$height){
                    $newHeight=$height;
                    $newWidth = $img_width*$newHeight/$img_height;
                }

            }

        }


        if($newHeight!=0 && $newWidth!=0){
            return new Box(ceil($newWidth),ceil($newHeight));

        }
        else
            return null;

    }
```

I don't know witch extension you use. I use [Imagine Extension for Yii 2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-imagine-index.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$imgpathlogo = App::param("upload_path").'outletlogo'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
                $imgpathlogothumb100 = App::param("upload_path")."outletlogo". DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."thumb100". DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
                $imgpathlogothumb200 = App::param("upload_path")."outletlogo". DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."thumb200". DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
///////////////////Chek Outlet New Logo Images////////////////
                                if ($_FILES['OutletMaster']['name']['outlet_logo'] != "") {
                                    $imagelogo=$files['OutletMaster']['name']['outlet_logo'];
                                    $logofilename=explode(".", $imagelogo);
                                    $logofileext = $logofilename[count($logofilename) - 1];
                                    $newlogofilename = uniqid(). "." . $logofileext;
                                    $model->outlet_logo = $newlogofilename;
                                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['OutletMaster']['tmp_name']['outlet_logo'],$imgpathlogo.$newlogofilename);

                                    //////////////////Creating Thumbnail For Outlet Logo///////////////////////////
                                    $ext = explode(".", strtolower($newlogofilename))[1];
                                    $src = $imgpathlogo.$newlogofilename;
                                    if ($ext == 'gif')
                                        $resource = imagecreatefromgif($src);
                                    else if ($ext == 'png')
                                        $resource = imagecreatefrompng($src);
                                    else if ($ext == 'PNG')
                                        $resource = imagecreatefrompng($src);
                                    else if ($ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'jpeg')
                                        $resource = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
                                    $width  = imagesx($resource);
                                    $height = imagesy($resource);

                                    $thumbWidth100 = 100;
                                    $desired_width100 = $thumbWidth100;
                                    $desired_height100 = floor( $height * ( $thumbWidth100 / $width ) );
                                    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width100,$desired_height100);
                                    imagecopyresized($virtual_image,$resource,0,0,0,0,$desired_width100,$desired_height100,$width,$height);
                                    imagejpeg( $virtual_image, "{$imgpathlogothumb100}{$newlogofilename}" );

                                    $thumbWidth200 = 200;
                                    $desired_width200 = $thumbWidth200;
                                    $desired_height200 = floor( $height * ( $thumbWidth200 / $width ) );
                                    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width200,$desired_height200);
                                    imagecopyresized($virtual_image,$resource,0,0,0,0,$desired_width200,$desired_height200,$width,$height);
                                    imagejpeg( $virtual_image, "{$imgpathlogothumb200}{$newlogofilename}" );
                                }
```

Comment: I want to do this with extension

Comment: extension will not give exect image to you that will give error of about 5px